# Using colormaps with the Iris-dataset in matplotlib pyplot gives an error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to get colormaps working with the Iris dataset form sklean. Colormaps work as expected when I use de dataset from Seaborn, but I have no clue why it does not work with the sklearn set. Any suggestions?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# works
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
colors = {'setosa': 0, 'versicolor': 1, 'virginica': 2}
plt.scatter(x=iris.sepal_length, y=iris.sepal_width, c=[colors[i] for i in iris.species], cmap='viridis')
plt.show()

# does not work
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
plt.scatter(x=iris.data[:,[0]], y=iris.data[:,[1]], c=iris.target, cmap='viridis')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shapes of the arrays used for the x and y coordinates need to match with the shape of the array used for colormapping. Here, the x and y arrays have shape `(150,1)`, while the c array has shape `(150,)`. Best do not use lists to index arrays if the result shall be a 1D array, i.e. use `iris.data[:,0]` instead of `iris.data[:,[0]]`:

```
plt.scatter(x=iris.data[:,0], y=iris.data[:,1], c=iris.target, cmap='viridis')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the colors list as a list of singletons.

> `c=[[i] for i in iris.target]`